# Set a shopping world for a specific subshop

Tags: shopware

I am trying to set a shopping world for a specific subshop in a shopware installation. I have multiple subshops with different domains related to the same thing, in other words, I have for example, cheap-clothes.com, really-cheap-clothes.com, the-cheapest-clothes.com and they all display the same website, the domain is the only thing that change, so the categories are the same on every subshop.

That said, how is it possible to set a shopping world for a specific subshop?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible when separating the category-trees. The display of shopping worlds is controlled by category assignment. You need to duplicate the categories and the product assignments in order to show a different content.

I would recommend developing your own plugin or a theme for each subshop where you can seapate the shopping worlds based on their ID.

Comment: I actually created a theme for that specific subshop, based on the main theme (I am changing the design a little bit on this specific subshop). But I don't know how to separate the shopping worlds based on their ID, could you please guide me how to do it?

Comment: I finally understood how to do it, I duplicated the categories and then assign them to the new theme "Configuration > Basic settings > Shop settings > Shops" picked the specific subshop I wanted and then assigned the duplicated category to then in the shopping worlds create a new one and also assign it to the new duplicated category.

Comment: You don't need to duplicate the shopping worlds, when you only want to change the home shopping world. Please have a look at this line: https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.4/themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/home/index.tpl#L44

By changing the $emotion.id to a specific ID you can modify the assignment. When you assign a shopping world from the backend, it will do the same (put the id to the variable $emotion.id)